# Arc diagram not working in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to add  arc diagram to my angular project using D3 at the basic level.

I copied the sample code from this link,
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/arc_highlight.html

And added it in my angular file to try out but unfortunately it not working properly.

I am not sure but I believe it able to extract the json and create arc diagram. I am newbie with D3, below are files

Also is it right way to add the code in angular ?

**arc-diag.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from "d3";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-arc-diag',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './arc-diag.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./arc-diag.component.css']
})
export class ArcDiagramComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'Arc Diagram';

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {

        var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 30}, 
                       width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,  
                       height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            
        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g") .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            
            // Read dummy data
            d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_network.json", function( data) {
            
                // List of node names
                var allNodes = data.nodes.map(function(d){ return d.name })
            
                // A linear scale to position the nodes on the X axis
                var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]).domain(allNodes)
            
                // Add the circle for the nodes
                var nodes = svg.selectAll("mynodes").data(data.nodes).enter()
                    .append("circle").attr("cx", function(d){ return(x(d.name))})
                    .attr("cy", height-30).attr("r", 8).style("fill", "#69b3a2")
            
                // And give them a label
                var labels = svg.selectAll("mylabels").data(data.nodes).enter().append("text")
                    .attr("x", function(d){ return(x(d.name))}).attr("y", height-10)
                    .text(function(d){ return(d.name)}).style("text-anchor", "middle")
            
                // Add links between nodes. Here is the tricky part.
                // In my input data, links are provided between nodes -id-, NOT between node names.
                // So I have to do a link between this id and the name
                var idToNode = {};
                data.nodes.forEach(function (n) { idToNode[n.id] = n; });
                // Cool, now if I do idToNode["2"].name I've got the name of the node with id 2
            
                // Add the links
                var links = svg.selectAll('mylinks').data(data.links).enter().append('path')
                .attr('d', function (d) {
                    const start = x(idToNode[d.source].name)    // X position of start node on the X axis
                    const end = x(idToNode[d.target].name)      // X position of end node
                    return ['M', start, height-30,    // the arc starts at the coordinate x=start, y=height-30 (where the starting node is)
                    'A',                            // This means we're gonna build an elliptical arc
                    (start - end)/2, ',',    // Next 2 lines are the coordinates of the inflexion point. Height of this point is proportional with start - end distance
                    (start - end)/2, 0, 0, ',',
                    start < end ? 1 : 0, end, ',', height-30] // We always want the arc on top. So if end is before start, putting 0 here turn the arc upside down.
                    .join(' ');
                }).style("fill", "none").attr("stroke", "black")
            
                // Add the highlighting functionality
                nodes.on('mouseover', function (d) { // Highlight the nodes: every node is green except of him
                    nodes.style('fill', "#B8B8B8")
                    d3.select(this).style('fill', '#69b3b2')
                    // Highlight the connections
                    links
                        .style('stroke', function (link_d) { return link_d.source === d.id || link_d.target === d.id ? '#69b3b2' : '#b8b8b8';})
                        .style('stroke-width', function (link_d) { return link_d.source === d.id || link_d.target === d.id ? 4 : 1;})
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                    nodes.style('fill', "#69b3a2")
                    links
                        .style('stroke', 'black')
                        .style('stroke-width', '1')
                    })
            })
            
            // text hover nodes
            svg
                .append("text")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", "#B8B8B8")
                .style("font-size", "17px")
                .attr("x", 50)
                .attr("y", 10)
                .html("Hover nodes")
    }
}
```

**arc-diag.component.html**

```js
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

**Actual diagram generated**

[image]

**Expected diagram**

[image]

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using, if it's d3v5 or 6, then you need to update `d3.json("file",function(data) {` to `d3.json("file").then(function(data) {`

Comment: To echo what @AndrewReid said... I attempted to use an online editor (Plunker) to replicate your problem.  No matter how I specified a `d3` version in the package.json it always pulled in a very recent version (6.3).  The example code you are following is quite dated (version 4).   [Here it is running](https://plnkr.co/edit/HlLMvNIzJ5NI7MeW?preview), tweaked with a `.then` for versions > 4.

Comment: yup, thats worked :)